# Использование QWebEnginePage::acceptNavigationRequest

Tags: c++, qt

Объясните начинающему программисту, как использовать [QWebEnginePage::acceptNavigationRequest](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#acceptNavigationRequest), пытался на прямую - не получилось.... Нужно для перехода по ссылкам в QWebEngine

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky , мне нужно сделать так, чтобы обрабатывались клики по ссылке, проблема в том, что я не знаю как использовать функцию!